# What part of DecimalFormatSymbols accounts for the space between number and percent sign for Locale.FRANCE?

Tags: java, internationalization, formatting

If you run this:

```
DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat)(NumberFormat.getPercentInstance(Locale.US));
System.out.println(format.format(0.55));
```

It will print "55%", but for French there is a space before the percent sign:

```
DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat)(NumberFormat.getPercentInstance(Locale.FRANCE));
System.out.println(format.format(0.55));
```

It will print "55 %".

Looking at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html I cannot figure out what method would tell me about that space?  The getPercent() returns only "%".

Comment: Have you tried stepping the entire formatting process with a debugger?